# Installed gnome, but it isn't applied

Tags: gnome

I installing gnome using command `sudo apt-get install gnome`, and I choose gde from the x windows menu, but when I reboot nothing happened, I'm still stacked with unity. Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to do:

1. Log out of Ubuntu.
2. In the top right corner of the text area where you place your password (next to your name), you should see an Ubuntu icon. Click it.
3. Select Gnome.
4. Log back in.
5. Profit!